# Looping through composer require with ansible task

Tags: ansible

I feel like this should be really straight-forward, but I've been pouring over the ansible docs and other answers here, and I'm stuck.

What I want to do is to set up an array or list of composer packages to be used in a `composer require` statement using the ansible composer object.

So, I've got a `set fact` like so to define the modules:

```
- name: Define modules to be required
  set_fact:
    modules:
      - vendor1/package1
      - vendor2/package2
      - vendorN/packageN
```

I've put this in the top of my ansible project so it's easily accessible and editable (It'd be sweet to figure out how to simply define the packages in a yaml file as vars, and then use `set_fact` in the playbook, but I'll stick to scope here)

With this in mind, I then have a role in the project with a composer task where I want to require each of these:

```
- name: "Require packages"
  composer:
    command: require
    arguments: {{ modules_to_be_required }}
    working_dir: "{{ app['directory'] }}"
```

Originally, I did this using `with_items` like so:

```
- name: "Require packages"
  composer:
    command: require
    arguments: "{{ item }}"
    working_dir: "{{ app['directory'] }}"
  with_items
    - vendor1/package1
    - vendor2/package2
    - vendorN/packageN
```

This does work; however, it causes a `composer update` to run with each iteration of `with_items` which takes far too long.  To me, it makes more sense to take the list of packages to be required, convert them to a string separated by spaces, and then pass that as an argument.

In my research I found that I could convert a list to a string with the `join` filter, so I tried this:

```
- name: "Require packages"
  composer:
    command: require
    arguments: {{ modules | join(" " ) }}
    working_dir: "{{ app['directory'] }}"
```

But, this gives me a YAML syntax error:

```
The offending line appears to be:
command: require
arguments: {{ modules | join(" ") }}
            ^ here
```

I've tried wrapping `"{{ modules | join(" ") }}"` but I get yelled at for the quotes in the parenthesis.

Am I approaching this idea in the right way, or what questions do I need to ask to get to the answer?  Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join filter can use single quotes

```
arguments: "{{ modules | join(' ') }}"
```

or you can escape the double quotes

```
arguments: "{{ modules | join(\" \") }}"
```

or you can use single quotes for the variable and double for the join

```
arguments: '{{ modules | join(" ") }}'
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the detailed explanation -- much-appreciated.